# Multipoint GRE on ubuntu with netplan

Tags: networking, server, netplan, interface

I'm reading the netplan documentation and it looks like it does not support multipoint GRE (for NHRP via eg. OpenNHRP).

It's the gap in the documentation or did netplan do not intentionally support multipoint GRE at all and it's not a replacement for ifupdown and legacy /etc/network/interfaces.d/* configs? If so then can netplan and ifupdown be used simultaneously?

I'm trying to port this configuration into the netplan project:

```
root@2483:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces.d/mpgre0
auto mpgre0
allow-hotplug mpgre0
iface mpgre0 inet static
netmask 255.255.255.0
pre-up ip tunnel add $IFACE mode gre key XXX ttl 64 || true
up ip link set $IFACE multicast on
up opennhrp -d
post-down ip tunnel del $IFACE
address XXX
```

Netplan forcing the remote to be defined, which don't make sense for NBMA GRE:

```
/etc/netplan/10-mpgre.yaml:6:7: Error in network definition: tun0: missing 'remote' property for tunnel
      mode: gre
      ^
```